# I am currently building a React app with Google OAuth2.0, it is not redirecting after completing login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Built a simple react login page using OAut2.0 but does not redirect to a new page after login, rather lands back on the login page.

I want my page to redirect to the dashboard after login.

Google API console has been configured with Authorized JavaScript origins( URIs) and Authorized redirect URIs.

If possible you can share how to use passport JS for reactjs.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login'; // or import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';

const responseGoogle = (response) => {   console.log(response); } 
ReactDOM.render(<GoogleLogin
    clientId="658977310896-knrl3gka66fldh83dao2rhgbblmd4un9.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}
    onFailure={responseGoogle}
    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}/>, 
    document.getElementById('googleButton') );
```

Comment: Hi @Akash, could you share a code snippet of how you're currently running your code and then we can be able to help you.

Comment: @Claeusdev I have added the snippet in my question

Answer (score 0):

so in your `responseGoogle` method, instead of `console.log()` you could run `return this.history.push("/dashboard")` this would redirect to your dashboard or the route that is the dashboard or you could send a snippet of your response logged to the console for us to see

Comment: It still redirects to the same login page.